# change datagridviewtextbox column value from dropdownlist control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a window form that have two comboboxes and a datagridview which is bind with different datasource. one is for datagridview and another one is for both comboxes. This datagridview has two columns named like account1 and account2. these columns contains same value as in comboboxes.

Now my problem is that if i want to change combobox value then the current selected row value shuold change as in combox.

Suppose combobox contains values from 1 to 10. and currently selected value is 3 which is same in datagridview. If i change this combobox value from 3 to 7 then datagridview value should change from 3 to 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your query, you may follow as below:

```
dataGridView1[1, 2].Value = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();//Here, 1 represents row, 2 represents column.
dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

Both of the lines works same as per I know; just different syntax. You may use either.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

are u trying to do this

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;//to get the selected text
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;//to get the selected text index
```

if not elaborate ur question clearly